# How can I prove this proposition that seems obvious?

Tags: geometry

The following problem seems obvious:

> If $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEF$ are such that $|AB|=|DE|$ and $|BC|=|EF|$ but $\angle ABC > \angle DEF$ then $|AC|>|DF|$.

But I can't to write a formal proof!! Any suggestion, thanks in advance!!

Comment: To aid in web-searching, this is called the "Hinge Theorem".

Comment: This is helpful!! Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the Law of Cosines?

Comment: Yes! But I was looking for a classical approach!!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the  diagram shown below::--

[image]